# Метод VK API message.get выводит только 200 сообщений, не получается вывести все сообщения

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Нужно получить все сообщения(их гдето 2000 шт), которые в дальнейшем, по id пользователя будут помещены в массив, а получается вывести только 200 сообщений (это ограничение самого метода), пытаюсь это сделать в цикле при помощи смещения offset. Но что то я делаю не так.
Вот код:

```
$vk_config = array(
    'app_id'        => '****',
    'api_secret'    => '****',
    'callback_url'  => '',
    'api_settings'  => 'messages,friends',// In this example use 'friends'.
    'token'         => '***'
    // If you need infinite token use key 'offline'.
);

try {
    $vk = new VK\VK($vk_config['app_id'], $vk_config['api_secret'], $vk_config['token']);

        $access_token = $vk_config['token']."<br>";

        echo 'access token: ' . $access_token;

        $user_friends = $vk->api('friends.get', array(
            'uid'       => '***',
            'fields'    => 'uid,first_name,last_name',
            'order'     => 'name'
        ));
        $user_send_messeges = $vk->api('messages.get', array(
            'out'             => '1',
            'count'           => '200',
            'time_offset'     => '0',
            'offset'           => '0'
        ));
        $arr_uid_all = array();
        $arr_uid_message = array();
        $i = 0;
        // var_dump($user_send_messeges['response']);
        while ($user_send_messeges['response'][$i]) {
            echo $user_send_messeges['response'][$i]['uid']."<br>";
            ++$i;
            $user_send_messeges = $vk->api('messages.get', array(
            'out'             => '1',//1 - сообщения исходящие
            'count'           => '200',//мак. кол-во сообщений(зашито в методе)
            'time_offset'     => '0',//смещение по времени
            'offset'           => $i//смещение, необходимое для выборки определенного подмножества сообщений 
        ));
        }

} catch (VK\VKException $error) {
    echo $error->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

У метода `messages.get` есть параметр `offset` который позволяет начинать выборку с определенного сообщения. То есть первая выборка будет offset=0 count=200, следующая offset=200 count=200 (т.к. первые 200 сообщений уже получили), третья - offset=400 count=200 (т.к. первые 400 сообщений уже получили) и т.д.

В качестве примера:

```
$count = 200;
$i = 0;
while($continue){
    $request = $vk->api('messages.get', array(
        'out'             => '1',
        'count'           => $count,
        'offset'          => $i
    ));
    if(count($request['response']['items']) == 0){
        $continue = false;
    }
    $i+=$count;
}
```

Код просто для примера, не проверялся.